# .desktop files do not get registered

Tags: ubuntu, .desktop

I've been repeatedly running into issues with .desktop files not being registered on my Ubuntu machine. I'm at my wits end to be honest, the exact same situation works on my desktop but not on my laptop. The current .desktop file that's plaguing me is this one:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=LogSeq
Exec=/home/rick/Museum/applications/Logseq-linux-x64-0.8.17.AppImage
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/rick/.local/share/icons/logseq.png
```

I put it in ~/.local/share/applications/logseq.desktop with no result. I have refreshed my session with Alt+F2->r with no result. I have shut down, rebooted, and logged out of my system, with no result. The exact same file works on my desktop with a simple refresh of my session, no problem at all.

I've run the file through the `desktop-file-validate` command with no errors being detected. I've used the `desktop-file-install` command which put the file in the /usr/share/applications/ directory with no result.

The .desktop file and the icon file were both sym-linked, but I turned them into normal files, no linking. This also was not the issue.

The system on which it doesn't get registered is running Ubuntu 22.04.1.

Someone, please tell me I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: not an answer, I've been asking me same question for a while : https://askubuntu.com/questions/969231/17-10-18-04-tls-desktop-files-are-no-longer-trusted